# How to use this in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, dom-events

In jQuery we use:

```
$("p").click(function(){$(this).hide();});
```

In the above statement `this` is very important, because it hides only that `p` element on which we click. But instead if we use `"p"` at the place of `this` it will hide all the `p` elements when we click any one of the `p` element.

I was wondering if there is any way to generate same effect using JavaScript. I tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p").onclick = function(){this.style.display:none;}
```

and

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p").onclick = function(){document.getElementsByTagName(this).style.display:none;}
```

But none of this works.

Comment: can you try     this.style.display = 'none'; inside click event

Comment: "I was wondering is their any way to generate same effect using javascript" - nope, it only works with jQuery, which uses dark magic.

Comment: Related, but probably not a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8801099/1075247

Comment: I want to avoid jquery. but i think their is no easy way to get same effect using javascript. so i think i should use jquery instead of writing complex javascripts.

Comment: @Alex: How so? Standard DOM event handler use the same kind of magic when invoking the listener functions in the context of the current target element.

Comment: @YoYo stop talking when you have no clue! `this` is a javascript expression, jQuery has nothing to do with that. you dont need jQuery to use `this`

Comment: @Bergi i thought the sarcasm was obvious

Comment: @Alex You were also quoted in an answer ;)

Comment: "this.style.display:none;" that's not javascript, for starters

Comment: check this link to understand the concept of THIS https://scotch.io/@alZami/understanding-this-in-javascript

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to iterate over each element and then use `addEventListener` to attach an event to it:

```
var allP = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(i=0; i< allP.length; i++) {
    allP[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      this.style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zt7zdwnk/)**

Comment: or use event delegation :)

Comment: @Alex: not recommended unless the dom is loaded dynamically :)

Comment: @Milind Anantwar: not recommended - why you think so?

Comment: @degr: there is no point in putting load on parent elements when elements can have there own events.

Comment: sorry, I miss this comment

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, delegation tends to improve performance by reducing the number of event listeners bound, which can have significant memory improvements for large collections of nodes. Certainly a small amount of delay is introduced to the event callbacks, but this is usually negligible, and unnoticeable due to the asynchronous user behaviors that cause the callbacks in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

As [Alex wrote in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034019/how-to-use-this-in-javascript#comment65418331_39034019):

> > I was wondering if there is any way to generate same effect using JavaScript.
>
> Nope, it only works with jQuery, which uses dark magic.

jQuery is misusing `this`. In fact it should be used only in classes, not in callbacks.

To achieve the same effect using native DOM:

- Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all `<p>` elements.
- Convert the result ([`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)) to an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- Call the [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to execute a function on all elements.
- Assign a `click` event listener to each element using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.
- Finally, inside the event listener, assign `'none'` to `el.style.display` to hide the element.

### Live demo

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p"))
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => el.style.display = 'none'))
```

```html
<p>Try clicking any of the paragraphs.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla purus metus, ullamcorper tempus augue interdum, efficitur vulputate lectus.</p>
<p>Vestibulum ullamcorper ultrices egestas.</p>
<p>Pellentesque volutpat, est ut convallis interdum, elit metus dapibus ex, non consectetur sem est et felis.</p>
```

Comment: An event handler could easily be seen as a *method* of the DOM element, especially when attached via `.onclick =`. Using `this` inside it would make quite some sense then.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but anyway when using arrow functions, `this` doesn't refer to the current element.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. so don't complain about those :-) Btw, a "method" could be reused, unlike the arrow function closures which need to be recreated in every loop iteration.

Comment: -1 "In fact it should be used only in classes, not in callbacks". This assertion is *heavily* opinionated, and very incongruous. JavaScript didn't even *have* classes until ES6, whereas the ability to bind `this` on functions has *always* existed with `call` and `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

**Step1:** Get all Paragraphs

**Step2:** Attach a clickListener to each item in Paragraphs

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>

<body>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>

    <p>This is another paragraph</p>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function paragraphsClickHandler() {
        this.style.display = "none";
    }

    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var i;

    for(i=0; i<paragraphs.length; i++)
        paragraphs[i].addEventListener("click", paragraphsClickHandler);


</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `document.getElementByTagName` does not exist.

You should use `document.getElement**s**ByTagName` instead which returns a collection:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].onclick = function(){
    this.style.display= "none";
}
```

Or use this for the same `$("p")` example:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].onclick = function(){
        this.style.display= "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only attach the event listener to the first `<p>` found in the DOM

Comment: Sure. The example is for demonstrating  this keyword as asked in the question

Comment: But the example in the question applies the handler to _all_ `<p>` and only hides the one that is clicked, your example does **not** create the same effect

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to prefer arrow functions or cannot trust `this` for some reason, you can grab [e.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead:

```
const elems = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
const handleClick = e => console.log(e.currentTarget); //logs the clicked element

for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

document.getElementsByTagName("p") returns a collection. You need to iterate and hook the event on each element as:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"))
                     .forEach(function(element) {
                                element.onclick = function() {
                                 element.style.display = 'none';
                                }
                      });
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using getElementsByTagName, it will give an array object, not a single element, so you need to iterate it in a loop and bind the click event with every element as below:

```
var domLength = document.getElementsByName('p').length;
for (var i=0; i<domLength; i++) {
    document.getElementsByName('p')[i].style.display = none;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: what is btnSubmit?

Comment: anyway, bad decision, because you perform dom search in each loop iteration.

Comment: @ degr  , I just forgot to replace btnSubmit with P, now correct that

Answer (score -2):

```
 var bubblingToEle = function (target, type, value) {
        while(target){
            switch (type){
                case 'nodeName':
                    if(target.nodeName === value){
                        return target;
                    }
                    break;
                default :
                    break;
            }
            target = target.parentNode;
            if(target.nodeName === 'HTML'){
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var target = e.target,
            isPTag = bubblingToEle(target, 'nodeName', 'P');

        if(isPTag){
            isPTag.style.display = 'none';
        }
    })
```

I think this is better, no need to bind many listeners.